# javascript game ( 3 in line ) line check logic

Tags: javascript

i've been in a battle to sort this problem since yesterday and i fear that i've gotten tunnel vision.

**The game:**

first player to make a line of 3 of a kind (xxx or 000) wins.
http://jsfiddle.net/brunobliss/YANAW/

**The catch:**

Only the first horizontal line is working!!! **I can make it all work** using a lot of IFS but repeating the same code over and over again is often a good indicator that i'm doing somethin wrong

**The problem:**

bruno.checkWin(); will check if there's a line or not, the guy who presented me this game chalenge told me that it is possible to check the lines with a for loop and that i should use it instead of IFS. I can't solve this without IFS unfortunately...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
        <title> </title>
        <style>
            #jogo {
                border: #000 1px solid;
                width: 150px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                margin-left: -75px;
                margin-top: -75px;
            }
            #jogo div {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
                width: 28px;
                height: 28px;
                padding: 10px;
                font-size: 20px;
                border: #000 1px solid;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #reset {
                font-family: Verdana;
                width: 153px;
                height: 30px;
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                cursor: pointer;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: -76px;
                margin-top: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <script> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="jogo"> </div>
        <div id="reset"> RESET </div>
        <script>
        var ultimo = "0";
        var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
                    var jogo = document.getElementById('jogo');
            var cell = jogo.getElementsByTagName('div');
        var bruno = {
            init: function () {
                var jogo = document.getElementById('jogo');
                for ( i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++ ) {
                    var cell = document.createElement('div');
                    cell.onclick = function () {
                        // variavel publica dentro do obj?
                        ultimo = (ultimo == "x") ? 0 : "x";
                        this.innerHTML = ultimo;
                        bruno.checkWin();   
                    };
                    jogo.appendChild(cell);
        }
            },
            checkWin: function () {
                var jogo = document.getElementById('jogo');
                var cell = jogo.getElementsByTagName('div');
                // as diagonais nao verificar por loop
                for ( i = 0 ; i < cell.length ; i=i+4 ) {
                    switch(i) {
                        case 0:
                        if (cell[0].innerHTML != '') {
                            bruno.checkFirst();
                        }
                        case 4:
                        if (cell[4].innerHTML != '') {
                            bruno.checkFirst();
                        }
                        case 8:
                        if (cell[8].innerHTML != '') {
                            bruno.checkFirst();
                        }                       
                    }
                        /*
                    } else 
                    if (i == 4 && cell[4].innerHTML != '') {
                        bruno.checkCenter();
                    } else 
                    if (i == 8 && cell[8].innerHTML != '') {
                        bruno.checkLast();
                    }*/
            }
        },
        reset: function () {
            var jogo = document.getElementById('jogo');
            var cell = jogo.getElementsByTagName('div');
            for ( j = 0 ; j < cell.length ; j++ ) {
                cell[j].innerHTML = "";
            }
        },
        checkFirst: function () {
            if (cell[0].innerHTML == cell[1].innerHTML && cell[1].innerHTML == cell[2].innerHTML) {
                alert("linha horizontal");
                return false;
            } else 
            if (cell[0].innerHTML == cell[3].innerHTML && cell[3].innerHTML == cell[6].innerHTML) {
                alert("linha vertical");
                return false;
            }
        },
        checkMiddle: function () {
            // check vertical and horizontal lines from the center
        },
        checkLast: function () {
            // check last horizontal and right edge vertical
        }

};
        window.onload = function () {
            bruno.init();
        };
        reset.onclick = function () {
            bruno.reset();
        };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider a single function that has the logic for checking three values passed to it. Then call that function three different ways, a loop of horizontal, a loop of vertical and both diagonals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a more 'compact' version of your code. No switch statements. Have a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/YANAW/1/

Here's the code, for those who prefer to read it here. Important/updated functions are **checkWin()** and **checkCells()**.

```
var bruno = {
    init: function () {
        var jogo = document.getElementById('jogo');
        for ( i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++ ) {
            var cell = document.createElement('div');
            cell.onclick = function () {
                // variavel publica dentro do obj?
                ultimo = (ultimo == "x") ? 0 : "x";
                this.innerHTML = ultimo;
                bruno.checkWin();   
            };
            jogo.appendChild(cell);
        }
    },
    checkWin: function () {
        var jogo = document.getElementById('jogo');
        var cells = jogo.getElementsByTagName('div');

        // Scan through every cell
        var numRows = 3;
        var numColumns = 3;
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
        {
            // Determine cell's position
            var isHorizontalFirstCell = ((i % numColumns) === 0);
            var isVerticalFirstCell = (i < numColumns);
            var isTopLeftCorner = (i == 0);
            var isTopRightCorner = (i == 2);

            // Check for horizontal matches
            if (isHorizontalFirstCell
                && bruno.checkCells(
                    cells, i, 
                    (i + 3), 1))
            {
                alert('Horizontal');
            }

            // Check for vertical matches
            if (isVerticalFirstCell
                && bruno.checkCells(
                    cells, i,
                    (i + 7), 3))
            {
                alert('Vertical');   
            }

            // Check for diagonal matches
            if (isTopLeftCorner
                && bruno.checkCells(
                    cells, i,
                    (i + 9), 4))
            {
                alert('Diagonal');
            }

            if (isTopRightCorner
                && bruno.checkCells(
                    cells, i,
                    (i + 5), 2))
            {
                alert('Diagonal');
            }            
        }
    },
    reset: function () {
        var jogo = document.getElementById('jogo');
        var cell = jogo.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for ( j = 0 ; j < cell.length ; j++ ) {
            cell[j].innerHTML = "";
        }
    },
    checkCells: function(cells, index, limit, step) {
        var sequenceChar = null;
        for (var i = index; i < limit; i += step)
        {
            // Return false immediately if one
            // of the cells in the sequence is empty
            if (!cells[i].innerHTML) 
                return false;

            // If this is the first cell we're checking,
            // store the character(s) it holds.
            if (sequenceChar === null)
                sequenceChar = cells[i].innerHTML;

            // Otherwise, confirm that this cell holds
            // the same character(s) as the previous cell(s).
            else if (cells[i].innerHTML !== sequenceChar)
                return false;
        }

        // If we reached this point, the entire sequence
        // of cells hold the same character(s).
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: and that works like a charm ! Not sure i'm familiar with some of that code though, gotta give it a close inspection. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If you have any question about specific bits, just ask them here and I will gladly explain. I should have included more comments in the code.

Comment: I sure do need help understanding some bits of code, for instance, the part where you comment determin cell's position, i do not get the assignment var something = ( i == 2 )  ???

Comment: Essentially you have 9 cells which are arranged in a 3x3 grid.
So the index of each cell would look like this:
-- first row:[0][1][2]
-- second row[3][4][5]
-- third row [6][7][8]

So if the index == 2, then I know I'm in the top right corner

Comment: yes i understand the array of cells what i dont get specifically is that variable assignment, i mean, var five = 5 means that five will be 5, but var five = ( something === 0 ) is something i dont understand

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I think I know what you mean. Basically I'm assigning a boolean (true/false) value to the variable. You see, between the parentheses, I put a 'test'. In the case of top right corner, the test can be read as: is 'i' equal to '2', which in code looks like (i == 2). So basically I'm assigning the value of the 'test' (i == 2) to the variable 'isTopRightCorner'. It's just a quick technique to assign boolean values. The long format would have been: if (i == 2) isTopRightCorner = true; else isTopRightCorner = false;